# Python. How to define an Items object within my inventoryRead method and then Call the inventoryRead method

Tags: python, object, methods

In my inventoryRead how can I properly define an Items object. Also, how do I run this method

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jburk/OneDrive/Desktop/Deft Project/quickMart.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Items:
  File "C:/Users/jburk/OneDrive/Desktop/Deft Project/quickMart.py", line 34, in Items
    inventoryRead('self')
  File "C:/Users/jburk/OneDrive/Desktop/Deft Project/quickMart.py", line 24, in inventoryRead
    item1 = Items()
NameError: name 'Items' is not defined
```

code

```
class Items:

    # Constructor to initilize an item object
    # An item has  name, quantity, price, member price, and taxing status
    def __init__(self, name, quantity, price, memPrice, taxStatus):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.memPrice = memPrice
        self.taxStatus = taxStatus

    
    def inventoryRead(self):
        txt = ""
        count = 0
        f = open("inventory.txt", "r")
        inList = []
        item1 = Items()
        print(item1)
        for line in f.readlines():
            item1.name = line[0:line.find(":")]
            print(item1)
            print(item1.name)
            inList[count] = Items()
            txt = line.next()
            print(txt)

    inventoryRead('self')
        

    #arr = f.readlines()
    #print(arr[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be smarter if you had an `Item` and a separate `ItemMangager` or `Items` class. I'm going to call it Items from now on.
Items would contain some store every Item in (for example) a list and Items loads them from the file, but also saves them to same.

You try to create an instance of the class you are currently in, the main way you would edit this file is through the **self** prefix you used before to modify this instances attributes.

The example I provide is done using a .txt file for storage to keep to your way of doing it, although it would probably be smarter to use an actual database module like `sqlite`, you should have a look into that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#Item holds one record of sth
class Item():
    def __init__(self,name, quantity, price, memPrice, taxStatus):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.memPrice = memPrice
        self.taxStatus = taxStatus

class Item_Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
        self.data_file_path="records.txt"
    def load_data(self):
        with open(self.data_file_path,"r") as f:
            contents= f.read()
            for i in contents.split("\n"): #splits every line into a new string
                data=i.split(" ") #asuming every line has the attributes space-separated
                item=Item(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4])
                self.items.append(item) #saving the new created Item instance in the mangagers items list
    def save_data(self): #overwriting
        with open(self.data_file_path,"w") as f:
            for i in self.items: #i = item instance
                f.write("{} {} {} {} {}".format(i.name,i.quantity,i.price,i.memPrice,i.taxStatus))
    
    def create_item(self):
        name=input("Name: ")
        quantity= input("Quantity: ")
        price=input("Price: ")
        memPrice= input("MemPrice: ")
        taxStat = input("Tax Status: ")
        item=Item(name, quantity, price, memPrice, taxStat)
        self.items.append(item)
    
    def display_data(self):
        for i in self.items:
            print(i.name,i.quantity,i.price,i.memPrice,i.taxStatus)
```

Hope this helps, if you have any further questions, just comment under this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues here:

1. Your code is obviously faulty, see below, and
2. You have made some strange design choices.

**Code Error:**

Your error comes from line: `inventoryRead('self')`

This is wrong because:

- you do not write `self` into a class method call. It is passed by itself.
- Your method call is outside of context. It is not part of another method in the class, while it obiously isn't an attribute.

Sort off "working" version of your code would be:

```
class Items:
    ''' Constructor to initilize an item object
    An item has  name, quantity, price, member price, and taxing status'''

    def __init__(self, name=None, quantity=0, price=0, memPrice=0, taxStatus=None): # fill the default values or you will have an error in inventory function
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.memPrice = memPrice
        self.taxStatus = taxStatus

    
    def inventoryRead(self):
        txt = ""
        count = 0
        f = open("inventory.txt", "r")
        inList = []
        item1 = Items() # <-- works like this only if you have defaults in your __init__ definition
        print(item1)
        for line in f.readlines():
            item1.name = line[0:line.find(":")]
            print(item1)
            print(item1.name)
            inList[count] = Items()
            txt = line.next()
            print(txt)

items = Items()
items.inventoryRead()
```

This would work now but it surelly isn't what you want...

**Design choice**

1. You have an Item --> make it a class
2. You have an inventory? --> make it a class!
3. Manipulate your code from within Inventory
4. **You should really read some examples and tutorials on python OOP, since it would seem you don't really feel comfortable with how it works.**

Now for a quick working example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Item:
    def __init__(self,name, quantity=0, price=0, memPrice=0, taxStatus=0):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        self.memPrice = memPrice
        self.taxStatus = taxStatus

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def inventoryRead(self):
        # your function to collect items from file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inventory = Inventory()
    inventory.inventoryRead()
```